# Java: Why can't this code work, it says that my variable cannot be resolved

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class HowManyToKeep {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int currentcandies;
        int currentamountofpokemon;
        int howmanycandiestoevolve;
        int keepamount;
        int x =0;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter how many candies you have: ");
        currentcandies = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter how many pokemon you have: ");
        currentamountofpokemon = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter how many candies to evolve: ");
        howmanycandiestoevolve = sc.nextInt();
        sc.close();

        for (int i=0;i<100;i++) {
        int grosstotalcandies = currentcandies + currentamountofpokemon;
        int howmanycanevolve = grosstotalcandies / howmanycandiestoevolve;
        int totalamountofcandies = howmanycanevolve + grosstotalcandies;
        }

        keepamount = totalamountofcandies / howmanycandiestoevolve;
        System.out.println("The total amount you should keep is: " + keepamount);

    }


}
```

---

So my question is, why does it say that the variable "totalamountofcandies" cannot be resolve when I defined it inside the loop? How should i get it to work

Comment: because it´s defined in the scope of the `for` loop, and hence doesn´t exists after it anymore.

Comment: The aim of this code is to automatically calculate the maximum amount of pokemon you can evolve in pokemon go when having a huge amount of pokemon and candies of the same type

Comment: Hint: read some java code style guide lines. You use camelCase for variable names, and surprise, all of a sudden grossTotalCandies becomes somehow human readable!

Comment: Thanks guys, I've got what i needed, so sorry about my stupidity in Java, very new to all of this

Answer (score 4):

The scope of `totalamountofcandies` is only inside the loop. In order to access it outside the loop, you must declare it before the loop.

Besides that, I'm assuming that you want to add all the values collected in the loop and not overwrite the value of `totalamountofcandies` in each iteration :

```
int totalamountofcandies = 0;
for (int i=0;i<100;i++) {
    int grosstotalcandies = currentcandies + currentamountofpokemon;
    int howmanycanevolve = grosstotalcandies / howmanycandiestoevolve;
    totalamountofcandies += howmanycanevolve + grosstotalcandies;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable is declared in for loop (scope is within that for loop). You are trying to access it outside for loop. At this place, the variable is not available to the java compiler. So its throwing an error.This should work for you.

```
int totalamountofcandies = 0;
for (int i=0;i<100;i++) {
int grosstotalcandies = currentcandies + currentamountofpokemon;
int howmanycanevolve = grosstotalcandies / howmanycandiestoevolve;
totalamountofcandies += howmanycanevolve + grosstotalcandies;
}
```

Now you can access totalamountofcandies anywhere within that program.